# How do you look for classic/normative/standard books about an established branch of mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, learning, book-recommendation

If you want to immerse yourself in a branch of mathematics (e.g. linear algebra and linear optimisation) which is new to you, then you often look for standard books which you can rely on. You could call them *classic*, *normative*, *established*, *popular*, *widely-accepted*, etc. Typically, such work is referred to in introductory courses. If you are lucky, you are attending a relevant course (e.g. at university) held by a lecturer who could enumerate advisable literature. Otherwise, how can you quickly find/identify the literature to start out with - e.g. the 1-3 most standard textbooks of the branch - without already being an expert?

Comment: Nowadays I more often than not find that the internet search engine of choice points me to a relevant (book-recommendation) thread on math.SE. (e: At least if the branch is mainstream enough.)